# how to center a div with background image within another div

Tags: html, css

there is a div with class test that i can not place center in div with col-lg- 12. it is my code:

```
<style>
      .test{
        background-image: url('asa.jpeg') no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
       width:150px; 
       height: 150px; 
        border-radius: 87px;
        }
</style>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="test"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what do i do?

Comment: remove the **no-repeat;** in background-image

Comment: @Roy I removed it, but nothing happened

Comment: @BenM I edit and explained.

Comment: It's working, check this https://jsfiddle.net/6hd5btx2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `margin:0 auto;` for class `.test` and remove `no-repeat`

```css
.test {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x150) ;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 87px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or
if you want to use `no-repeat` then use `background:` instead of `background-image:` and `background-size:cover;`

```css
.test {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x150)no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 87px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fix the problem using bootstrap, just **place empty `div` added with class `col-lg-5` above current `div`** and edit next `div` as `col-lg-1`. So the next div will get placed in the center (6th) in the grid system.

```css
.test{
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/300');

  
          background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
       width:150px; 
       height: 150px; 
        border-radius: 87px;
/*    margin:auto; */
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">

    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with your div margin. You can easily check it with chrome developer tools <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

The **solution** is to set the **`margin` to `auto`**.

```css
.test{
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/300');
          background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
       width:150px; 
       height: 150px; 
        border-radius: 87px;
   margin:auto;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your `.test` element has a fixed width, you can use automatic margins to centre it within the parent element:

```css
.test{
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/408/287');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 150px; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:150px; 
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that we also need to remove the `no-repeat` definition on the `background-image` (since that's not a valid definition).